# Collapsible closes when i type on a TextInput

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput, react-native-collapsible

As i say in the tittle, i have a collapsible and the state value for my input

```
const [colapse1, setColapse1] = useState(false);
const [folioActual, setFolioActual] = useState("");
```

And i have a button which takes care of closing and opening my collapsible,
my issue is that whenever i type on my input, the collapsible collapses and i have to touch my button again to open it again, my textInput looks like this:

```
<TextInput value={folioActual}
onChangeText={(valor) => setFolioActual(valor)}
              style={styles.valorFolio}
            ></TextInput>
```

Comment: Please share the code related to the collapsible.